# Any suggestions on shows/movies/youtubers to increase French listening skills?

Tags: ressources, cinéma

I have been looking for ways to improve my French listening skills and so far I have only found one youtuber that has helped me (Françaisavecpierre) Do any of you have any suggestions? And can you give me some links to watch/listen to your suggestions? Thank you! I'm still very bad at listening, and I can only understand people who speak clearly and with simple words (Even then I only understand 70%). If the thing has transcripts that would be great :)

Answer (score 2):

A YouTube channel of French humorists (with, most of the time, English subtitles if you don't understand) is "GoldenMoustache".

I can give you a lot of references but maybe it's better if you give your taste. 
Also I don't know YouTube channels for French lessons because I'm French.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to improve one's skills is to watch movies on CD and **turn on close captioning in French**. You can also see movies on Netflix with close captioning in the original language. That is really the best way to link what is spoken and how it is written. If you do not understand what is said, at least seeing the written form of it will help you or you can ask questions about those written forms here.

I have found this to be the single most significant way of improving language skills in any languages. Depending on where you live and your internet access, there may be other services that provide movies with close captioning in the original language. Advice: stay away from sub-titles. It will not improve your French.

This will get  you started:http://filmfra.com/
Don't worry about understanding every little thing at first. Just listen, read and repeat. Question later....

Comment: Unfortunately, http://filmfra.com/ does not work anymore...

Answer (score 2):

RFI (Radio France Internationale) has a news podcast in "easy" French: 
http://savoirs.rfi.fr/fr/apprendre-enseigner/langue-francaise/journal-en-francais-facile

I improved my Swedish a lot with a similar program a few years ago. That works well because you can do it everyday for a short period of time. Learning a language requires a little bit of work on regular basis and news podcasts are perfect for that.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer recommand you to watch movies in french with subtitles (Fre or Eng). Fre subtitles should be better to read/listen at same time.

How about Disney's movies ? Less complicated expressions to begin :)

Then, I would suggest to take a look at TV advertisements (french channels). In that way, it is better to associate images/words in ads context.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend watching french movies, rather serious ones if possible, as humour is often linked with slang and familiar speech. Watching news might be a good way to improve as it deals with subject you're prone to know already.

However if you're already fine with listening to french news for instance, humour is a great way to improve furthermore.

- [France 24 (click on "Journal", top right corner)](http://www.france24.com/fr/)
- [Arte, franco-german channel](http://info.arte.tv/fr)
- Manon des sources (film about Pagnol's novel)
- Les valseuses
- Le salaire de la peur
- Les tontons flingueurs (classic french comedy)
- La grande vadrouille (same)

Comment: About Les Tontons Flingueurs, or any Audiard for that matters... Even a french kid nowadays wouldn't understand half of the dialogue in those movies, as it is like 90% old slang. Would definitely NOT recommand it for a french learner.

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend the youtube channel [Axolot](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kgTFiIRiefs), he talks about all sorts of mysterious, weird, fascinating stuff. I think it's a very good choice because:

- He speaks pretty **slowly**, and is very easy to understand
- Most of his videos are **subtitled**, in French but also in multiple languages
- It's absolutely fascinating
- What's on screen is often not too important, so you're not worried about missing stuff because you're focused on listening

Answer (score 0):

I also want to improve my hearing, and indeed is a bit troublesome. My best solution to the problem thus far is:

Get a hold of any season of **The Simpsons** in french, there are several ways to do so quickly... go figure.

Then go to [Simpsons park](http://www.simpsonspark.com). This websites has scrips to all episode word for word. From there I suggest you study the scripts before watching the episode and try to follow along when you play it. There are several ways you could practice I guess.

I like The Simpsons because the series in itself is decent, and the production value is higher than usual when it comes to dubbed series. Except for Marge, listening to her voice induces rage.